# How to get the uri of images that have their path stored in string Array?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

ERROR in LOGCAT:

> E/StorageException: No content provider: [/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Garbett.jpeg, /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Hampi-9.jpg]
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: [/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Garbett.jpeg, /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Hampi-9.jpg]

Next time when the app is installed, this **ERROR** comes up in **LOGCAT** :

> E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
> An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
> Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0

This is the fragment where I'm trying to upload the image to the firebase storage and download the URL:

```
public class AddServiceFragment extends Fragment
{
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    private Button addService, addServiceImages;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private imageAdapter imageAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> Images = new ArrayList<>();
    private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> getResult;
    private List<String> imageUrlList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_service, container, false);

        addService = v.findViewById(R.id.add_service_button);
        addServiceImages = v.findViewById(R.id.add_service_images);
        recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.add_service_recyclerView);
 

        imageAdapter = new imageAdapter(Images);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);


        addServiceImages.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), AlbumSelectActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_LIMIT, 6);
                getResult.launch(intent);
            }
        });


        getResult = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result)
            {
                ArrayList<Image> images = result.getData().getParcelableArrayListExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_IMAGES);
                Images.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++)
                {
                    Images.add(images.get(i).path);
                }
                imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        });



        addService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (Images.size() != 0)
                {
                    StorageReference reference = firebaseStorage.getReference();

                    for (int i = 0; i < Images.size(); i++)
                    {
                        StorageReference storageReference = reference.child(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                        storageReference.putFile(Uri.parse(Images.get(i))).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot)
                            {
                                storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>()
                                {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(@NonNull Uri uri)
                                    {
                                        imageUrlList.add(uri.toString());
                                    }
                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener()
                                {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e)
                                    {
                                        storageReference.delete();
                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error" + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }


                }

             }
               
        });

        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: You get a `FileNotFoundException`. So most likely the file doesn't exist, right?

Comment: No sir, the images r visible in the recycler view.